# Getting error while deploying solace docker image

Tags: image, docker, solace

I'm using the following command to run docker solace image:

```
docker run -p 8080:8880 -p 55555:55555 --shm-size=2g --env 
'username_admin_globalaccesslevel=admin' --env 
'username_admin_password=admin' --name=solace solace-app:8.9.0.1008- 
community
```

I receive the following error

```
Host Boot ID: 0e071b66-a316-465f-9adb-bc088d8edffe
Starting VMR Docker Container: Wed Apr 4 12:34:20 UTC 2018
SolOS Version: soltr_8.9.0.1008
2018-04-04T12:35:16.271+00:00 <syslog.warning> 1898a041b742 rsyslogd: environment variable TZ is not set, auto correcting this to TZ=/etc/localtime  [v8.33.1 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2442 ]
2018-04-04T12:35:16.271+00:00 <syslog.info> 1898a041b742 rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.33.1" x-pid="273" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
2018-04-04T12:35:17.270+00:00 <local6.info> 1898a041b742 root[271]: rsyslog startup
2018-04-04T12:35:18.283+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Log redirection enabled, beginning playback of startup log buffer
2018-04-04T12:35:18.289+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Container user 'appuser' is now in 'root' groups
2018-04-04T12:35:18.295+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: /usr/sw/var/soltr_8.9.0.1008/db/dbBaseline does not exist, generating from confd template
2018-04-04T12:35:18.301+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Finished playback of log buffer
2018-04-04T12:35:18.901+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[297]: /usr/sw                        ipcCommon.cpp:479                     (BASE_IPC     - 0x00000000) main(0)@solevent(?)                           WARN     SolOS is not currently up - aborting attempt to start solevent process
2018-04-04T12:35:18.908+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 pam_event[296]: WARN Failed raising event, rc: 2, event SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_OPENED shell(sudo),<296>,internal,root,root
2018-04-04T12:35:19.504+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[299]: /usr/sw                        ipcCommon.cpp:479                     (BASE_IPC     - 0x00000000) main(0)@solevent(?)                           WARN     SolOS is not currently up - aborting attempt to start solevent process
2018-04-04T12:35:19.510+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 pam_event[296]: WARN Failed raising event, rc: 2, event SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATION_SESSION_CLOSED shell(sudo),<296>,root,root
2018-04-04T12:35:19.518+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Updating dbBaseline with dynamic instance metadata
2018-04-04T12:35:19.661+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Mirroring host timezone
2018-04-04T12:35:19.667+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Generating SSH key
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA1 RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
2018-04-04T12:35:20.064+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Starting solace process
2018-04-04T12:35:20.882+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT  INFO: Launching solacedaemon: /usr/sw/loads/soltr_8.9.0.1008/bin/solacedaemon --vmr -z -f /usr/sw/loads/soltr_8.9.0.1008/SolaceStartup.txt -r -1
2018-04-04T12:35:24.744+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:732                          (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Determining platform type: [  OK  ]
2018-04-04T12:35:24.903+00:00 <local6.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: INFO Checking system resources
2018-04-04T12:35:24.906+00:00 <local6.err> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: ERROR Platform POST Violation [022]: Required system resource missing, 4.0 GiB RAM required to support connection scaling limit 1000, 2.0 GiB detected
2018-04-04T12:35:24.909+00:00 <local0.err> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: /usr/sw/loads/soltr_8.9.0.1008/scripts/CommonHwInit.pm:107 **ERROR Platform POST Violation [022]: Required system resource missing, 4.0 GiB RAM required to support connection scaling limit 1000, 2.0 GiB detected**
2018-04-04T12:35:24.912+00:00 <local6.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: INFO Checking storage
2018-04-04T12:35:24.982+00:00 <local6.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: INFO Checking Tsc reliability
2018-04-04T12:35:28.172+00:00 <local6.info> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: INFO Commiting POST status for Platform (FAILED)
2018-04-04T12:35:28.181+00:00 <local6.err> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: ERROR Platform 1 FATAL POST violation detected
2018-04-04T12:35:28.184+00:00 <local0.err> 1898a041b742 root: EXTERN_SCRIPT vmr-post[369]: /usr/sw/loads/soltr_8.9.0.1008/scripts/CommonHwInit.pm:107 ERROR Platform 1 FATAL POST violation detected
2018-04-04T12:35:28.188+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:920                          (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Child terminated with failure status: command: '$SOLENV_ORIG_CURRENTLOAD_REALPATH/scripts/vmr-post --logs --commit --soldaemon' PID: 369 status: 512 sigRxd: 0
2018-04-04T12:35:28.225+00:00 <local0.info> 1898a041b742 root[393]: /usr/sw/loads/soltr_8.9.0.1008/scripts/commonLogging.py:76    WARN   Running vmr-solredswitch
2018-04-04T12:35:28.228+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:732                          (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Monitoring SolOS processes: [  OK  ]
2018-04-04T12:35:28.233+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        Generated_commonReturnCodes.cpp:135   (BASE         - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Unknown exit value 1, defaulting it to 'fail'.
2018-04-04T12:35:28.233+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        Generated_commonReturnCodes.cpp:135   (BASE         - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Unknown exit value 1, defaulting it to 'fail'.
2018-04-04T12:35:28.233+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:1007                         (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Child terminated with failure status: command: 'pkill -P $PPID dataplane-linux' PID: 395 rc: fail status: 256 sigRxd: 0
2018-04-04T12:35:28.239+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:3457                         (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Syncing filesystem before shutdown ...
2018-04-04T12:35:28.246+00:00 <local0.warning> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:3462                         (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000000) main(0)@solacedaemon                          WARN     Shutting down router
2018-04-04T12:35:28.246+00:00 <local0.err> 1898a041b742 root[1]: /usr/sw                        main.cpp:3441                         (SOLDAEMON    - 0x00000001) main(0)@solacedaemon                          ERROR    ######## System shutdown complete (Version 8.9.0.1008) ########
```

Comment: Reference : https://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/Docker-Containers/Set-Up-Docker-Container-macOS.htm#Step

Comment: Fixed formatting.

Answer (score 3):

By default Docker (at least on MacOS) only allocates 2 Gb RAM whereas the VMR requires 4Gb.

Hence the error message:4.0 GiB RAM required to support connection scaling limit 1000, 2.0 GiB detected

On the Mac use the Docker|Preferences...|Advanced and move the "Memory" slider to above 4Gb. I have mine set to 4.2 Gb.

Comment: Thanks Mic Hussey, it working now by changing memory in Docker|Preferences...|Advanced